# How to reproject a table using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, coordinate-system, srid

To reproject a table into different CRS is a very common practice in geospatial analysis. However, I am still struggling to reproject my table in PostGIS, after reading loads of Q&A related to this topic.

Here I got a table with a set of points. The original SRID is `28356`

```sql
SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'pts', 'geom');
```

[image]

I'd like to reproject the table to 4326 for further analysis.

Firstly, I used `ST_Transform`, but failed with this error message:
`ERROR:  Geometry SRID (4326) does not match column SRID (28356)`

```sql
UPDATE pts SET geom = ST_Transform(geom,4326);
```

Then I tried `ALTER` table but got the same error: `ERROR:  Geometry SRID (4326) does not match column SRID (28356)`

```sql
ALTER TABLE pts 
  ALTER COLUMN geom 
  TYPE Geometry(Point, 4326)
```

Finally, the `UpdateGeometrySRID` function seems running correctly and the `Find_SRID` query return 4326 as expected.

However, when loading the modified layer to the map canvas, they are not in the correct location.

```sql
SELECT UpdateGeometrySRID('public', 'pts', 'geom', 4326);
SELECT Find_SRID('public', 'pts', 'geom');
```

Is there anything wrong with my query?

Comment: It's also common practice in geospatial analysis to project from one data object to another. Your attempt at *in-situ* change is the issue here. I would suggest creating a new table for the new SRID.

Comment: or just a new column - there is no problem having multiple geometry columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to alter the table column and transform the data in one step:

```
ALTER TABLE pts 
  ALTER COLUMN geom 
  TYPE Geometry(Point, 4326) 
USING ST_Transform(geom, 4326);
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you try specifying a source SRID and target SRID, one of the options in the [documentation][1], in the query used to load the table?

```
SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 28356, 4326);
```

Another option would be, as @Scorpio mentioned, to create a new table with the desired SRID

```
CREATE TABLE new_table
  AS (SELECT ST_Transform(geom, 28356, 4326)  FROM old_table);
```